# if loop within for loop in shell script not working

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following shell script in place to send out an email alert. When I only have the for loop everything works fine but when I try to add the if condition it does not seem to work and returns a null message body everytime. A snippet from the script is as below:

```
for host in $servers
do
connections=`ssh $host "netstat -a | grep ES | wc -l"`
echo "$connections" >> debug.log
echo "$host" >> debug.log

if [$connections -gt 0]
then
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $emailmessage
echo "Host: $host needs to be checked" >> $emailmessage
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------" >> $emailmessage
echo "$connections" >> $emailmessage
else
echo "Everything is fine"
fi

done
```

I always end up getting the `line 21: [49: command not found` error when i try to execute the script. I tried debugging but I figured out my script is not even getting inside the if loop.

Can someone please let me know what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

/rd

Comment: Terminology quibble: an if statement is not a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be space around `[` and `]` also its better to put variable in quotes, so update your line as

```
...
if [ "$connections" -gt 0 ] ; 
then
...
```

Comment: @rond As a tip for the future, [Shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) will automatically point out silly mistakes like this.